# How to get distinct record from two tables in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two table showin below

news (table name)

```
NewsId   NewsDate
1       25-03-2014

2       29-03-2014
```

newsImageGal (table name)

```
newsSr   newsId      newsImages
1           1        images/i.jpg
2           1        images/j.jpg
3           1        images/k.jpg
4           2        images/l.jpg
5           2        images/m.jpg
6           2        images/n.jpg
```

i want a result like

```
 NewsId   NewsDate          newsId      newsImages
  1        25-03-2014         1          images/i.jpg
  2        9-03-2014          2          images/l.jpg
```

i have tried using join query and group by function but it shows duplicate multiple records how to solve this query?

Comment: Can you explain the logic how you get the result?

Comment: last date in `NewsDate` could be `29-03-2014` ??

Comment: @ganesh .its demo data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT a.NewsId,
       a.NewsDate,
       b.newsImages
FROM   news  a
       JOIN (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY newsid ORDER BY newssr) rn,
                    *
             FROM   newsImageGal) b
         ON a.NewsId = b.newsId
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Key here is to find the first image that got added into `newsImageGal` table per `newsid`. 
so use the `window function` to create Row_number per `newsid` in order of `newsSr`.

```
SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY newsid ORDER BY newssr) rn,
                        *
FROM   newsImageGal
```

From the above query you can see the `rn=1` is the first image that got added into the `newsImageGal` join the result with `news` table and filter the result with `rn=1`

Answer (score 1):

You can write as

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( SELECT N.NewsId
        ,N.NewsDate
        ,NIG.newsImages
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  N.NewsId ORDER BY NIG.newsSr ASC)
        AS rownum
 FROM news N
 JOIN newsImageGal NIG ON N.NewsId = NIG.newsId
 )
SELECT NewsId,
       NewsDate,
       newsImages
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
select distinct ng.newsId, ng.newsImages
from (
select MIN(newsSr),newsId,newsImages
from newsImageGal 
group by newsId,newsImages) ng
join news ne
on ne.newsId=ng.newsId
```

Comment: no it returns all data having multiple images with same newsId

Comment: @user3863009 can you check now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select n.NewsId,n.NewsDate,g.newsImages
from news n
join newsImageGal g on n.NewsId=g.newsSr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.NewsId,
       n.NewsDate,
       ng.newsId,
       ng.newsimages
FROM   news n,
       (SELECT *,
               Rank()OVER(PARTITION BY newsId ORDER BY newsSr DESC) AS rank
        FROM   newsImageGal) ng
WHERE  n.NewsId = ng.newsId
       AND rank = 1
```